# why RSA public keys contains non-ascii characters?

Tags: rsa, base64

let's look at the public key in this post as an example: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/35105

> MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVxwTCpvKe4eCZ0FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUpwmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFncCzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ51s1SPrCBkedbNf0Tp0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZwIDAQAB

when I decode this base64 string using an online tool, I get a public key with some funny characters as below shows:
[image]

> 00
> *H
> ��0�;P8YcNEq0x&tG_)bFPd8TY5CJ5Dd1!U?oOe#9R>[5A0GONg�

I don't understand why it contains non-ascii characters, isn't that public key should be ascii format rather than unicode (which contains funny characters) format?

Comment: Why are you not using the decoder that was linked to that question?  The issue is the decoder you have selected isn't using the correct character set. The linked question explains what type of key this was, simply put, ASCII is the incorrect character set.

Comment: The decoded string is just a string of 1's and zeros which form a data structure.   ASCII is probably not a good way to represent that structure as it was originally only 7 bits (so how to interpret if the MSB [8th] is a 1 ???).  It would make a lot more sense to use a hex editor (as the original example) if you want to see the original layout of the bits, or openSSL if you want to parse the data structure.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why it contains non-ascii characters, isn't that public key should be ascii format rather than unicode (which contains funny characters) format?

No. The key is not ASCII; it is not made out of characters *at all.* Bytes are not required to represent text.

The format that you have is a "binary" structure, with most of the bytes directly representing numbers by their value. (Same as in image or audio files.)

For example, a 1024-bit RSA modulus would be directly stored as those 1024 bits, or 128 bytes, with their numeric value being used directly instead of being mapped to any kind of character. A few surrounding bytes are the ASN.1 serialization format boundaries.

This is literally why it was Base64-encoded in the first place. The whole purpose of Base64 is to transport non-text (non-ASCII) data in a "safe" ASCII-fied form.